# I want to better write require() path in the Renderer process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-packager

I was using modules in the Renderer process with require().

```
/* renderer.js */
const Vue = require('vue');
const marked = require('marked');
...
```

There is no problem when executing "electron .", but packaging will be "no such file or directory". (packaging with Electron-packager)

Just to solve this, put the js file I want to require () at the same directory as renderer.js and do as follows.

```
/* renderer.js */
const Vue = require('./vue.min.js');
const marked = require('./marked.min.js');
...
```

However, it is troublesome to put the js file.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the path.  You need to specify the path of vue and marked completely.  For example:
`var Vue = require("./model/vue");`

Comment: Sorry, what is the model of that require("./model/vue")?